# Форма выхода в сервлетах

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet

У меня есть форма выхода:

```
<form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
</form>
```

Но я хочу использовать ссылку `<a href="xxx" ...> </a>` вместо формы. Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: дублирование на буржуйском излишне

Comment: с _а_ проблематично послать _post_ запрос, без яваскрипта.

Comment: Может подскажите, как его сделать с ява скриптом?

Comment: опишите конкретные шаги, что вы хотите получить, а так же приведите пример, чем именно вы хотите заменить форму, или элемент внутри формы?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov, в данном случае, можете добавить свой собственный ответ с вашим вариантом решения, и добавить картинки туда, так как на них не информация для вопроса, а ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через ссылку нельзя делать `POST` запросы, только `GET`. Если есть возможность заставить работать обработчика формы с `GET` параметрами, то ссылку легко сделать:

```
<a href="LogoutServlet?submit=Logout">Выйти</a>
```

Если же трогать обработчик нельзя, то можно сделать форму невидимой и по нажатию ссылки отправлять форму:

```
<form id="logout" action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="logout" value="submit"> 
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="$('#logout').submit()">Выйти</a>
```

Или же можно полностью вынести форму в `javascript`. Только не забудьте подключить [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я уже смог написать свою реализацию по подобию.
<a href="javascript:formSubmit()">Exit</a>
<form action="LogoutServlet" method="post" id="Logout">
 <input type="hidden" value="Logout" />
</form>

Comment: Как я понимаю, в этом случае используется пост

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov, а я так старался(

Comment: Прошу прощения, мне просто показалось, что мой метод выглядит проще.

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov, а что за функция _formSubmit()_? и как вы используете _а_ **вместо** формы, если форма у вас так же осталась?

Comment: @Grundy у меня такой же вопрос

Comment: Если честно я писал не сам, а просто сделал по примеру, но на данный момент форма не отображается она hidden. Но это работает, секунду, кину скрин.

Comment: я прикрепил к начальному посту 2 скрина, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov ну да, вы вынесли отправку формы в отдельную функцию. Я же сделал это в `onclick`. Так что ваш вариант сложнее.

Comment: @MichaelPak, ну _сложнее_ это понятие относительное :-) зато у него не используется jQuery

Comment: @Grundy так можно и без `jquery`: `onclick='document.getElementById("logout").submit();'`

Comment: @MichaelPak, так именно эта строчка и была вынесена в функцию :-), кстати тут лучше не онклик, а href и `javascript:`, хотя без разницы :-)

Comment: @Grundy так я и не вижу смысла выносить одну строчку в функцию! )

Comment: @MichaelPak, вполне себе смысл, чтобы потом добавить проверку полей, нужно будет просто добавить текст в функцию

Comment: @Grundy, с этим соглашусь.